# Proof of this formula (multivariable function)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to prove this:
$$ x^2 f_{xx} + 2xyf_{xy} + y^2 f_{yy} = n(n-1) f(x,y) $$

when f is a homogeneous function of the root n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both sides are linear, you need only evaluate them with $f=x^ky^{n-k}$ for $0\le k\le n$. In other words, check $k(k-1)+2k(n-k)+(n-k)(n-k-1)=n(n-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint